# Why is my pivoted SQL returning all NULL values?

Tags: null, pivot

I have been agonizing over this for many hours and have decided to ask for help.  I have only done one other pivot and it was simpler than this.

What I am trying to do is join data from two table - incident and source and summarize the data since January 2014 by quarter.  Since we are almost half way through 2017 - Q1, that would be 13 columns.

My SQL does compile, but it returns NULL for each column.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT [ClientName],
       [1] AS [2014 - Q1],
       [2] AS [2014 - Q2],
       [3] AS [2014 - Q3],
       [4] AS [2014 - Q4],
       [5] AS [2015 - Q1],
       [6] AS [2015 - Q2],
       [7] AS [2015 - Q3],
       [8] AS [2015 - Q4],
       [9] AS [2016 - Q1],
       [10] AS [2016 - Q2],
       [11] AS [2016 - Q3],
       [12] AS [2016 - Q4],
       [13] AS [2017 - Q1]
FROM(
SELECT COALESCE(S.S_Name,'') AS [ClientName],
       (CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,I.opened) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,I.opened) AS VARCHAR(1))) AS [Period],
       COUNT(I.incidentno) AS [IncidentCount]
FROM incident I
LEFT OUTER JOIN source S ON I.SourceId = S.S_ID
WHERE S.S_ID = 'OP_Pac_ANZ'
GROUP BY COALESCE(S.S_Name,''), (CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,I.opened) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,I.opened) AS VARCHAR(1)))
)
src
PIVOT (SUM(src.IncidentCount)
FOR [Period] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13])) AS pvt
```

These are the actual results:

ClientName  2014 - Q1   2014 - Q2   2014 - Q3   2014 - Q4   2015 - Q1   2015 - Q2   2015 - Q3   2015 - Q4   2016 - Q1   2016 - Q2   2016 - Q3   2016 - Q4   2017 - Q1
ANZ NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

These are the expected results:

ClientName  2014 - Q1   2014 - Q2   2014 - Q3   2014 - Q4   2015 - Q1   2015 - Q2   2015 - Q3   2015 - Q4   2016 - Q1   2016 - Q2   2016 - Q3   2016 - Q4   2017 - Q1
ANZ 8   17  10  4   8   13  19  10  3   NULL    1   NULL    NULL

I am going to work on providing the sample data next.

Here is the amended SQL:

```
SELECT [ClientName],
       ['20141'] AS [2014 - Q1],
       ['20142'] AS [2014 - Q2],
       ['20143'] AS [2014 - Q3],
       ['20144'] AS [2014 - Q4],
       ['20151'] AS [2015 - Q1],
       ['20152'] AS [2015 - Q2],
       ['20153'] AS [2015 - Q3],
       ['20154'] AS [2015 - Q4],
       ['20161'] AS [2016 - Q1],
       ['20161'] AS [2016 - Q2],
       ['20162'] AS [2016 - Q3],
       ['20163'] AS [2016 - Q4],
       ['20171'] AS [2017 - Q1]
FROM(
SELECT COALESCE(S.S_Name,'') AS [ClientName],
       (CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,I.opened) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,I.opened) AS VARCHAR(1))) AS [Period],
       COUNT(I.incidentno) AS [IncidentCount]
FROM incident I
LEFT OUTER JOIN source S ON I.SourceId = S.S_ID
WHERE I.SourceId = 'OP_Pac_ANZ'
GROUP BY COALESCE(S.S_Name,''), (CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,I.opened) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,I.opened) AS VARCHAR(1)))
)
src
PIVOT (SUM(src.IncidentCount)
FOR [Period] IN (['20141'],['20142'],['20143'],['20144'],['20151'],['20152'],['20153'],['20154'],['20161'],['20162'],['20163'],['20164'],['20171'])) AS pvt
```

Here is the SQL to create the two tables and insert the data.

```
CREATE TABLE incident
(
incidentno nvarchar(255),
sourceid nvarchar(255),
opened datetime
);

CREATE TABLE source
(
s_id nvarchar(255),
S_name nvarchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO source VALUES
('OP_Pac_ANZ', 'ANZ');

INSERT INTO incident
(incidentno, sourceid, opened)
VALUES
('1506110002', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-11 02:36:00.000'),
('1506110100', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-11 21:48:00.000'),
('1506120010', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-12 03:00:00.000'),
('1501260175', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-01-26 23:34:00.000'),
('1501290278', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-01-29 19:40:00.000'),
('1502110143', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-02-11 15:28:00.000'),
('1501090237', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-01-09 16:52:00.000'),
('1506150148', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-15 23:31:00.000'),
('1506160142', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-16 23:19:00.000'),
('1506170005', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-17 04:10:00.000'),
('1506170113', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-17 20:53:00.000'),
('1507010002', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-01 00:49:00.000'),
('1507010006', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-01 03:36:00.000'),
('1507010012', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-01 05:06:00.000'),
('1507020104', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-02 22:21:00.000'),
('1507030002', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-03 03:01:00.000'),
('1507030003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-03 03:11:00.000'),
('1507080007', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-08 05:10:00.000'),
('1507080039', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-08 11:11:00.000'),
('1507080124', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-08 23:31:00.000'),
('1507100003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-10 01:39:00.000'),
('1507120001', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-07-12 00:02:00.000'),
('1503300232', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-03-30 21:37:00.000'),
('1405280003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-28 04:43:00.000'),
('1405280325', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-28 22:22:00.000'),
('1405290007', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-29 04:11:00.000'),
('1405290009', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-29 04:23:00.000'),
('1406030002', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-06-03 02:07:00.000'),
('1405140050', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-14 08:47:00.000'),
('1405140322', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-14 19:22:00.000'),
('1405140327', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-14 19:42:00.000'),
('1501120369', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-01-12 19:36:00.000'),
('1504200174', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-04-20 23:42:00.000'),
('1510080001', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-10-08 00:59:00.000'),
('1510080128', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-10-08 16:39:00.000'),
('1510120006', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-10-12 03:49:00.000'),
('1510120111', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-10-12 22:32:00.000'),
('1510120114', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-10-12 23:33:00.000'),
('1510130002', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-10-13 03:35:00.000'),
('1503040057', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-03-04 11:10:00.000'),
('1503300005', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-03-30 02:39:00.000'),
('1403110339', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-03-11 21:52:00.000'),
('1406150021', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-06-15 21:18:00.000'),
('1408130367', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-08-13 22:13:00.000'),
('1506190003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-19 00:18:00.000'),
('1406290015', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-06-29 19:59:00.000'),
('1406290016', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-06-29 20:03:00.000'),
('1410120030', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-10-12 21:20:00.000'),
('1408010001', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-08-01 03:13:00.000'),
('1408030020', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-08-03 23:38:00.000'),
('1408060301', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-08-06 22:08:00.000'),
('1403180346', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-03-18 21:29:00.000'),
('1405150357', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-15 22:42:00.000'),
('1405180033', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-18 20:24:00.000'),
('1405190025', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-05-19 07:31:00.000'),
('1402170070', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-02-17 11:07:00.000'),
('1407080003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-07-08 03:27:00.000'),
('1407130019', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-07-13 22:26:00.000'),
('1408190333', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-08-19 21:18:00.000'),
('1410150001', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-10-15 01:12:00.000'),
('1402240330', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-02-24 18:40:00.000'),
('1512210004', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-12-21 01:30:00.000'),
('1512210005', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-12-21 01:36:00.000'),
('1403310361', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-03-31 21:21:00.000'),
('1403030003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-03-03 02:46:00.000'),
('1403030417', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-03-03 19:40:00.000'),
('1410290005', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-10-29 00:38:00.000'),
('1412220320', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-12-22 21:10:00.000'),
('1506260012', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-26 03:50:00.000'),
('1506290005', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-29 03:11:00.000'),
('1506300145', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-30 21:06:00.000'),
('1506300150', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-06-30 23:09:00.000'),
('1406180002', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-06-18 00:43:00.000'),
('1406180003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-06-18 00:45:00.000'),
('1406220007', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-06-22 09:24:00.000'),
('1408280001', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-08-28 02:13:00.000'),
('1409070033', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-09-07 20:28:00.000'),
('1409080003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2014-09-08 01:12:00.000'),
('1508100003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-08-10 04:10:00.000'),
('1508110004', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-08-11 02:54:00.000'),
('1508130106', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-08-13 14:26:00.000'),
('1509300036', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-09-30 05:08:00.000'),
('1508190197', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-08-19 20:24:00.000'),
('1509230005', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-09-23 01:18:00.000'),
('1509230194', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-09-23 21:41:00.000'),
('1511230002', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-11-23 04:13:00.000'),
('1511240121', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2015-11-24 21:05:00.000'),
('1601240046', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2016-01-24 21:41:00.000'),
('1603200028', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2016-03-20 22:46:00.000'),
('1602010003', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2016-02-01 03:35:00.000'),
('1608090001', 'OP_Pac_ANZ', '2016-08-09 00:49:00.000');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that the `PIVOT` clause says `FOR [Period] IN ([1], [2], ...)` and those are not, in fact, values of `[Period]`.

```
FOR [Period] IN (['20151'], ['20152'], ...)
```

(or something similar, I'm not in a good place to test the exact syntax) should work.  If you don't want to specifically code the year/qtr values, you could use a ranking function over `Period` instead of `Period` directly (but this will still end up making some assumptions in terms of the number of values to show...)

As an aside, you have the "right" table from a `LEFT JOIN` in your `WHERE` clause, which will spoil the outer join.  You should probably move that condition to the join's `ON` clause.

Comment: OK - I think I fixed the pivot clause and the "right" table from a left join in the where clause.  Here is my new SQL, but I am still getting all NULL values returned.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the relationship could be rechecked?  If you retrieving the NULL values from your sample data, surely the COALESCE is finding no data from the first columns, which is likely to explain NULL on your data fields.

Comment: I took the COALESCE part out and I still get all NULL counts.  I would also like to point out the select statement for the raw data does pull the expected results.  I'm at a loss as to why I cannot pivot the output.